# package [...] does not exist

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, libraries

I'm stuck for some time now here. I'm trying to create a library that will make use of another Java library generated using swagger editor. I added the swagger library to the main module and apparently it doesn't show any resolve conflicts or what so ever... I can also use auto complete to state `import io.swagger.client.ApiClient`. Here is a prt screen:

[image]

When I run a simple test file that instantiates an EGroupsHandler class, I get this error. Which is odd to me because I can even Ctrl+Click to jump to the definition of the class inside the external libraries. Any help? I'm using

Gradle 7.0.1
IntelliJ 11.0.2

Comment: How did you add the swagger library to the main module? Via gradle build file or using "Project Stucture"?

Comment: I tried both, but honestly, I'm not even sure if the Gradle build way, worked. So I did add it throw Project Structure.

Comment: You build project using Gradle,so all needed dependencies should be added to build scripts.

Comment: I added implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) to build.gradle, and I added my .jar to the libs directory.

Comment: You may try to build your project from command line outside IDE.

Comment: but I can't build, I'm running gradle build outside the IDE, but I get the error I posted above

Comment: It means that library is not loaded for some reason. Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233930/discussion-between-joao-quintanilha-and-y-bedrov).